# Swift SideMenu show view controller

Tags: ios, swift, menu

So I'm having a table view controller and using https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu i'm trying to display a "slide in" sidebar which works, but it doesn't show me the view that I want in the sidebar is black

[image]

```
// Define the menus
let menuLeftNavigationController = UISideMenuNavigationController()
menuLeftNavigationController.leftSide = true
// UISideMenuNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController, so do any additional configuration of it here like setting its viewControllers.
SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController = menuLeftNavigationController

// Enable gestures. The left and/or right menus must be set up above for these to work.
// Note that these continue to work on the Navigation Controller independent of the View Controller it displays!
SideMenuManager.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
SideMenuManager.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.view)
```

When It clicks on the sidebar button I have this, which creates the animation but doesn't show the viewcontroller

```
func someAction(){
    present(SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    debugPrint("clicked")
}
```

[image]

Comment: the same issue. Unfortunately, author drops us from Issues :(

Answer (score 4):

On the repo readme, you will find your answer, take a look on the Customization 
 section https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#sidemenumanager.

Simply set menuFadeStatusbar = false

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuFadeStatusBar = false
```

From the previous link, you will find the following information : "Draws the `menuAnimationBackgroundColor` behind the status bar. Default is true.
If `menuFadeStatusBar` is true, this color is used to fade it. Default is black."

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the comment of the snippet you posted:

```
// UISideMenuNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController, 
// so do any additional configuration of it here like setting its viewControllers.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      let btnMenu:UIButton = UIButton()
    btnMenu.frame = CGRect(x: 20*valuePro, y: 20*valuePro, width: 40*valuePro, height: 40*valuePro)
    btnMenu.backgroundColor = .red
    btnMenu.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.displayMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnMenu)
@objc func displayMenu(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button Clicked")
    present(SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

## The SideMenu README

### Code Implementation

#### First:

`import SideMenu`

From a button, do something like this:

```
// Define the menu
let menu = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
// UISideMenuNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController, so do any additional configuration 
// of it here like setting its viewControllers. If you're using storyboards, you'll want to do something like:
// let menu = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightMenu") as! UISideMenuNavigationController
present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

## Answer

You need use `UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController:)`, not `UISideMenuNavigationController()`.

If you open the side menu from left, set `leftSide` to `true`.

```
let menu = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
menu.leftSide = true
present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Of course, you should give instance variable to `UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController:)`.

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)

It's pretty simple and it just works. You're creating an **JASidePanelController**, setting this class to empty viewcontroller in your Storyboard and making this controller initial. (do not forget to `import JASidePanels` at the top of the class)

Then, in this class, you're implementing `awakeFromNib()` method like this:

```
leftPanel = ..//instantiating menu controller
let centerController = ...//instantiating center controller
centerPanel = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerController)
```

That's it.
You can instantiate controller via their ID which can be set in Identity Inspector

```
let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) //instantiating a storyboard we will use for instantiating controllers
let someController = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "here_your_identifier_goes") as! YourControllerClass
```

[image]

Comment: even not swift 2... pity

Comment: Just leave Swift 2 :)

Comment: I mean, JASidePanelController in ObjC (

Comment: Did the fact its written in ObjC make you think so?

Comment: i'v look at sources, yes. I do not want to make bridges, better to avoid this. No problem anyway, thanks for the link